# Facebook Messenger - Unable to create cache Error On Win 7 Startup

Tags: windows-7, cache

Every time I start Win 7, I get the following Facebook Messenger related message appear in a 'notepad' window on my desktop.  Any ideas how to stop it?

```
[0105/225425:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(2086)] Corrupt Index file
[0105/225425:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(43)] Unable to move the cache: 5
[0105/225425:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\Facebook\Messenger\fbmessenger.cache to C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\Facebook\Messenger\old_fbmessenger.cache_000
[0105/225425:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(221)] Unable to create cache
```

Comment: I tried to tag this [facebook-messenger] and [errors] but I'm an underpriviledged user!  Shame on me :(

Comment: I've added 2 new tags,m but I can't add the errors tag.Error 5 often means access denied. So check the folder permissions.